# Fixing a corrupted .MP4 file. which might be a 3gp file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, video-codecs, 3gp

I have a  file called input.MP4 and it is corrupted. It's from a CCTV camera. I tried everything, `ffmpeg`, VLC convert,  no luck. However, I used `mediainfo` and `exiftool` and extracted the following info. I am wondering if someone can figure out if I can use any of this info to fix it or convert it to a usable format. I have a copy of it [here on my Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oa-2D4khX9nrJnAzocRmc6rRhaWu2Sc8)

`mediainfo` gave me this:

```
General
Complete name                       : input.MP4
Format                              : MPEG-4
Format profile                      : 3GPP Media Release 5
Codec ID                            : 3gp5 (3gp5/3gp4/avc1/mp42/isom)
File size                           : 5.77 MiB
IsTruncated                         : Yes
```

`exiftool` gave me this:

```
ExifTool Version Number          : 10.80
File Name                        : input.MP4
Directory                        : /home/tendi/Downloads
File Size                        : 5.8 MB
File Modification Date/Time      : 2018:07:21 19:09:03-04:00
File Access Date/Time            : 2018:07:21 19:30:48-04:00
File Inode Change Date/Time      : 2018:07:21 19:30:48-04:00
File Permissions                 : rw-rw-r--
File Type                        : 3GP
File Type Extension              : 3gp
MIME Type                        : video/3gpp
Major Brand                      : 3GPP Media (.3GP) Release 5
Minor Version                    : 0.0.0
Compatible Brands                : 3gp5, 3gp4, avc1, mp42, isom
Movie Data Size                  : 5899106
Movie Data Offset                : 44
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This appears to be 7-8 files fused into one. I detected 8 moov atoms and 9 mdat atoms!

Comment: Really? How could that have happened? Any ideas on how to seperate them? Fix them?

Comment: I suspect that it's not really multiple files, but either a) the filesystem entries contain the wrong lnked list for the file contents, referencing other files, and/or b) due to some I/O error, the data was flushed multiple times to different locations. In any case, I did some hex edit to get the first file and was able to get stream info, but decoding failed since the sample tables remain invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I received a mp4 video with codec '3gp5', which seems to be a predecessor to isom/mp41 codec.  I transcoded it with:

```
ffmpeg -i input-3gp5.mp4 -vc mp42  output.mp4
```

I was then able to play the video with html5 video tag.